# Android Fragment with RecyclerView not firing up click event

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, android-adapter

i am struggling since days to figure out why my click event is not firing up on items on a RecylerView.

i have the main Activity that uses a ViewPagerAdapter to show 4 fragments , one of the fragments uses a RecyclerView and an adapter to show items ( from Volley request ).

WelcomeActivity ---> ViewPagerAdapter ----> SearchListFragment ---> ProListAdapter

WelcomeActivity :

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//View
private BottomNavigationView navigation;

//viewPager
private ViewPager viewPager;
private ViewPagerAdapter mViewPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

    //Views
    navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    navigation.setSelectedItemId(0);

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    mViewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(mViewPagerAdapter);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    navigation.getMenu().findItem(R.id.navigation_home).setChecked(true);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    navigation.getMenu().findItem(R.id.navigation_search).setChecked(true);
                    break;
                case 2:
                     navigation.getMenu().findItem(R.id.navigation_favorites).setChecked(true);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    navigation.getMenu().findItem(R.id.navigation_settings).setChecked(true);
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
    }

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener()   {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_favorites:
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_search:
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_settings:
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    };
    }
```

ViewPagerAdapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new ProfessionalListFragment();
        case 1:
            return new SearchListFragment();
        case 2:
            return new FavoritesFragment();
        case 3:
            return new SettingsFragment();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 4;
}
}
```

SearchListFragment :

```
public class SearchListFragment extends Fragment{
View rootView;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ProListAdapter adapter;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
String url;
String prof;
ArrayList<User> pros = new ArrayList<>();

public SearchListFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle     savedInstanceState) {
    //Implementing View Pager
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_list, container, false);

    //RecyclerView
    recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(rootView.getContext(), 3));

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        url = getArguments().getString("url");
        prof = getArguments().getString("pro");
        sendRequest();
    }
}

private void sendRequest() {
    //Show ProgressDialog
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.loading));
    progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.dialog_wait));
    progressDialog.show();

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap();

    params.put("prof", prof);



    StringRequest jsonObjReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            //Response OK
            ....
                    adapter = new ProListAdapter(pros, getContext());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            ....
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //error
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            return params;
        }
    };

    //Adding the request to the queue along with a unique string tag
    MySingleton.getInstance(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
   }
   }
```

fragment_search_list.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".WelcomeActivity">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    tools:listitem="@layout/pro_card"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

ProListAdapter :

```
public class ProListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProListAdapter.ViewHolder>{

private ArrayList<User> itemsData;
private Context context;

public ProListAdapter(ArrayList<User> itemsData, Context context) {
    this.itemsData = itemsData;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.pro_card, parent, false);

    // create ViewHolder
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(context, itemLayoutView);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.nom.setText(itemsData.get(position).getName());
    holder.phone.setText(Long.toString(itemsData.get(position).getPhone()));
    holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar);
    holder.card.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.zoom_in));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return itemsData.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    public TextView nom, phone;
    public ImageView img;
    public CardView card;
    private Context context;

    public ViewHolder(Context context, View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);

        card = itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.card_pro);
        nom = itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.pro_nom);
        phone = itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.pro_phone);
        img = itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.pro_img);

        this.context = context;
        itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = getLayoutPosition();
        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "hi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

pro_card.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
android:id="@+id/card_pro"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
app:cardElevation="8dp"
android:background="@color/color_white">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pro_img"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/pro_nom"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pro_nom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/pro_phone"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/first_names"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pro_phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/us_phones"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried many options but none is working , what is the best way and where is my mistake ?

Comment: It's because you have not set click listener on any of the views in your adapter class

Comment: I did set it in the ViewHolder itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: Try logging something in the `onClick()` method one outside condition `position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION` an one time inside condition

Comment: not working , its not firing up onClick method.

Comment: Try logging in your ViewHolder's constructor

Comment: i log a message inside mu viewHolder constructor and I got it , but I have 2 log messages for 3 shown items , and for another search result for one item I got one log message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217382/discussion-between-danish-ansari-and-leonidas79).